# How can I replace some characters for x in a string?

Tags: c#, regex

I have some words like:

```
table
computer
mouse
...
```

and my objective is to left the first 3 letters and the others replace with letter x, like:

```
tabxx
comxxxxx
mouxx
```

I'm using c#.

Someone can help?

Comment: Can you describe your issue in more details??  This is a very vague question

Comment: @dave.2 I need to replace last letters with letter x and the first 3 letters doesn't change, but i don't know how to do this

Comment: Just use string method :             string[] inputs = { "table", "computer", "mouse" };
            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                string word = input.Substring(0, 3) + new string('x', input.Length - 3);
                Console.WriteLine(word);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @jdweng Thank you so much!

Comment: Perhaps:   ^(\w{3}).*$ replace with \1xxx

Comment: @user23512546 added answer for you.

Comment: You can use the following regex @"(?<=.{3})." and replace with 'x'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a new method. Obviously you have a reason for this function, so I would make sure the name represents that process i.e. ShowPassword. And as @jdweng stated, use the substring function.

**ReplaceStrFunction** method

This has 1 input which you will need to pass in you string array. It will then return an array of all of the updated string entries.

```
public static string[] ReplaceStrFunction(string[] strArray)
{
    //Initialise Count
    var count = 0;

    //Make new Array to store the amended strings. Use the passed in array to dynamically determine the length.
    string[] replacedStrItem = new string[strArray.Length];

    //Iterate over each item in the string array
    foreach (string strItem in strArray)
    {
        //Replace each substring afer 3 charcters with an 'X'
        replacedStrItem[count] = strItem.Substring(0, 3) + new string('x', strItem.Length - 3);

        //Increment count by 1 each iteration
        count++;    
    }

    //Return  string array full of amended items 
    return replacedStrItem;
}
```

Calling function:

```
    //Build String array
    string[] strArray = new string[]{"table","computer","mouse" };

    ReplaceStrFunction(strArray);
```

Comment: The important line can be shortened to `replacedStrItem[count] = strItem.Substring(0, 3).padright(strItem.Length, 'x');`.